# three.js - putting scene in a div

Tags: css, three.js, cdn

I've been looking for answers however can't seem to make it work for this specific scene.

https://codepen.io/rkimo/pen/vdwxJj

Basically I just want to have this blob in a div so I can put content before and after and be able to scroll past it.

If it makes it easier, I do not need to have the function where the scroll zooms in and out on the blob.

Thanks in advance

```
#blobcontainer {
  background:pink;
height:300px;
}




html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background: #1f1d26;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (preferably using [SO snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)). We don't need to see all of your code for making your blob--it can be replaced by a cube or something simple. Presenting enough code to replicate the problem will usually highlight what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't implement the function `handleMouseWheel`, so scrolling over your three.js scene will have no effect in three.js and it should just keep scrolling the page:

```
function handleMouseWheel(event) {
    // do nothing ...
}
```